# How to keep CDATA entries with NSXML with cocoa?

Tags: xml, cocoa, cdata, nsxml

I'm trying to export an XML file that is embedded in a bigger file, that source XML contains lots of CDATA like this one:

```
<Title><![CDATA[BLABLA BLABLA]]></Title>
```

When i save the file:

```
NSData *xmlData = [xmlDocument XMLDataWithOptions:0];
[xmlData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES] ;
```

all the CDATA is gone, i just get :

```
<Title>BLABLA BLABLA</Title>
```

How can i make it so that it saves the CDATA with it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The solution : add the flag NSXMLNodePreserveCDATA  and problem is solved.